# Should I spend upon medication or paying my debt?

Tags: debt, healthcare

I had fever from 3 days and I am taking medicine (prescribed by my Medical Practitioner). Today I ran out of my medicine. I am feeling much better but not too good. The situation is that I got 600 units of money today. I borrowed 550 units from a friend a week before. Today I can do one thing, either I buy my medicine (doctor recommended to take them more 3 days) or I can repay to my friend. What should I do? (Medicine will cost 550 units amount)

Edit: Antibiotics for fever. I don't know them, Not a medical student.

Comment: What kind of medication? What kind of fever? Do not stop taking antibiotics! You need to share more information to get any kind of useful response.

Answer (score 5):

In a sense, this is a question about how to prioritize your expenses when you have limited income and savings. Obviously, listen to your doctor! Your health comes first. Buy the medicine.

This question is also a lesson in the importance of having an emergency fund.

Answer (score 3):

Discontinuing antibiotics early can result in a resurgence of the infection, possibly in antibiotic-resistant form. **Do not discontinue medication early without a doctor's guidance and approval.**

If your friend can't wait a bit for the money when you need it for medical care, they aren't much of a friend.

Most antibiotics are fairly cheap these days. Are you really sure you can't do both?

As @rocky said, next time don't let yourself get that short on cash. You *need* enough of a financial reserve to handle emergencies.